# Nextjs multiple params to same route

Tags: routes, next.js

I'm creating a DELETE handlers for deleting by ID and another by Title, does anyone know how to set up my file structure so one route can handle both?

It's currently:
api -> reminders -> [reminderId]

Where [reminderId] is the route I use for `api/reminders/${reminderId}`, if I wanted to do `api/reminders/${reminderTitle}`, would I have to turn [reminderId] to [...params] and handle both there? Or get rid of the folder altogether and make a file called [...params].ts?

I cant do 2 different folders, one for [reminderId] and [reminderTitle] as NextJs doesn't allow this because they are the same route.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to handle both deletion by ID and deletion by title in the same route, you can modify your file structure as below
Rename the [reminderId] folder to  [[...params]] or whatever you decide to show that it can handle multiple params
Inside the [[...params]] folder, create a file called index.ts
In the index.ts file, you can access the params passed in the URL using the req.query object.

-api

-reminders

-[[...params]]

-index.ts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).